# How can I split the contents of a row into two columns in html to display better

Tags: python, html-table

I have a sqlite db and the data is in the format - ('value','timestamp').
I am using a html file to render the data on a flask application eventually.

index.html is as follows -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>{{ title }} - XYZ</title>
       </head>
          <body>
            <h1>Page for Information</h1>
             <p style="color:blue;"></p>
             <table style="width:100%">
             {% for row in data%}
              <tr>
             <td> {{ row }} </td>
             </tr>
             {% endfor %}
             <tr>
             </table>
             </body>
            </html>
```

Right now the flask app prints like this which is unstructured :

('17 days', '2018-11-30 13:52:55')
('17 days', '2018-11-30 13:53:42')

DO I need to split/remove parantheses/single quotes before passing to the html?

Comment: each row is a tuple and yes, you need to access tuple elements by indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the variables of the row individually (I've comma separated the 2 values but you can just leave a space):

```
<th>Value</th>
<th>Timestamp</th>
{% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row[0] }}</td> <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Should give you:

17 days, 2018-11-30 13:52:55 
17 days, 2018-11-30 13:53:42

If they are named values use:

```
{{ row.value }}, {{ row.timestamp }}
```

Comment: I suppose I need to use css styling to add spacing between columns and a border /title etc ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to put them into cells in a table for you with headings. Please accept as answer if this has worked.